# Azure AD - get user's profile photo, OAUTH access failure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to access the signed in user's Profile Photo in the context of an email app which uses EWS to connect to Office 365.

The app is registered on portal.azure.com with the following required permissions:

1. Office 365 Exchange Online -> Access mailboxes as the signed-in user via Exchange Web Services
2. Windows Azure Active Directory -> Sign in and read user profile

The EWS part works just fine, I'm able to sign the user in, get the access and refresh tokens, and perform EWS operations using "Authorization: Bearer access_token".

The part I'm having trouble with is getting the user's profile photo.

This is the docs I'm going by:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/photo-rest-operations

The API endpoint I'm trying to use is:

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo

... with "Authorization: Bearer access_token" header.

The above API returns this response:

> HTTP 403
>   {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied.
>   Check credentials and try again."}}

What could be wrong?

1. According to the above docs, getting user's photo should be possible using the user.read scope.
2. The "Sign in and read user profile" permission I mentioned above has a tooltip saying "User.Read", so I believe that's the right scope

[image: Azure AD User.Read permission / scope]

I've tried decoding my access token at jwt.io, it has: `"scp": "full_access_as_user"` - where is my User.Read scope, or does "full access" include "user.read"?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that you tried use v2 endpoint Rest API but you didn't register the Application with v2 endpoint.

User Photo API is only available on Azure AD v2 authentication endpoint, Not  Azure AD and Oauth:

[image]

You need to go to [**Microsoft Application Registration Portal**](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) to register your Application. For more details , you can refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#azure-ad-v2-authentication-endpoint).

Comment: Hi,@KostyaVasilyev. If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Wayne. Have seen those docs but somehow didn't "connect the dots".

1 - Is it true that the v2 authentication endpoint does not support either Exchange Web Services (EWS) or IMAP for accessing email (and calendar / contacts, for EWS)? Only the new Outlook REST APIs?

2 - Is there a way to get the user's profile photo using an Azure AD token (which we currently use for EWS access)?

Comment: 1. For now, v2 endpoint only supports Microsoft graph API and Outlook REST API. 2. I think we can only use v2 point to get user photos fow now. but I don't do a further test.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

Since we were not able to use OAUTH2 APIs for this -

- since and our app uses EWS (Exchange Web Services) already...

We just ended up using the GetUserPhoto command with the user's (account's) own email address.

Works fine.