# Get users profile image in AAD id token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

My app is authenticating users to Azure AD using OAuth/OIDC. Is there a way to get the users profile image included in the id token?

I can get the profile image via the MS graph API as described in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216781/azure-ad-get-users-profile-photo-oauth-access-failure), but ideally I can get this in back in the id token so that I don't have to make the additional request. Is this posisble, and if so; how would I go about achieving this?

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant get users profile image from AAD id token.

The best way of getting the picture is through MS Graph.

In MS Graph API, you can use the below endpoint to fetch photo from Azure AD:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value`

To get this, you need to set the app permission as

```
Profile photo of any user in the tenant including the signed-in user - User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All
```

To test your endpoints, sign in to [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#)

**Reference:**

[Azure AD Get photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get)

Comment: Thanks Hari. I added User.ReadBasic.All and User.Read.All, but I couldn't find User.ReadWrite.All. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Hi @Ryan.Bartsch, Thank you very much. Adding any one of the permissions will work, and we don't require all the permissions.

Comment: Where to set the app permission?